# タグ [テキストファイル] はどのような場合に使うべきタグですか？

Tags: サポート, タグ, タグwiki

[テキストファイル](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%86%e3%82%ad%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab) というタグがあるのですが、タグの説明を見てもどのようなときに使うべきタグなのかよく分かりませんでした。

このタグはどのような質問につけるべきタグですか？　タグの説明を改善したいです。

Answer (score 0):

参考までに、英語版では `text` や `text-files` タグがあります。

感覚的にはリッチテキストなどのような余計な情報を含まない「プレーンな」テキストファイルかな、とも思いますが、わざわざタグ付けが必要かは少々疑問です。

特に日本語環境だと文字化けに関する質問等が出てくる場合がありますが、こちらは `文字化け` タグが既にあります。

Comment: 同感で、ただ、改行コードについての[こちらの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/12897/19110)のようにプレーンなテキストファイルのみに関係した質問というのはありえるので、タグ削除まではやりすぎに思えました。このためタグを残しつつタグ wiki を改善したいのですが、どう書くと濫用を防げるでしょうか。